# Bash: iterate through files based on regex parameter

Tags: bash, loops

There are several posts about iterating through bash files like this:

```
count_files() {
    count=0

    for f in "filename_*.txt"
    do
        count=$(($count + 1))
    done
    echo "Current count:$count"
}
```

I need to pass in "filename_*.txt" as a param when calling the bash script.  Like this:

```
$: count_files.sh "filename_*.txt"

$: count_files.sh "different_filename_*.txt"
```

This, however, only gets the first file:

```
count_files() {
    count=0

    for f in $1
    do
        count=$(($count + 1))
    done
    echo "Current count:$count"
}
```

How do I pass in a regex param and iterate through it?

NOTE: counting the files is just an example.  If you have a simple way to do that, please share, but that's not the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `count_files.sh` script make sure you call function with quotes like this:

```
count_files "$1"
```

instead of:

```
count_files $1
```

Later will get you count=1 because wildcard will be expanded before function call to the first file name.

Comment: Ah, turns out that because I'm attempting to call this multiple times, like below, I need to add quotes when I pass the script params to the function  (it wasn't working with the last line `count $*`).
`count() {
    count=0

    for f in $1
    do
     echo "check:$f"
     count=$(($count + 1))
    done
    echo "Current count:$count"
}

count "$*"`

Comment: Correct always use quoted while passing arguments in bash.